Why positive part of Grignard Reagent does not react the reactant molecule?
Question:

While reacting with Grignard Reagent, why don't we react $\ce{MgBr+}$ with $\ce{O-}$ by forming ionic bond between them?
The question was solved in such a way that
in the first step after reaction of Grignard Reagent, negative charge was formed and then after neutralizing it, alcohol group was formed.
Answer:


Well, you get alcoholate (alkoxide) so there's obviously counterion. It's just not shown.

So what if they would react? What difference would that make?

Oxygen-Magnesium interaction play an important role, see figure 1 of this paper, for example.

Grignard reagent is not a mild reagent. It is a highly reactive reagent. It acts like a carbonanion, which is extremely unstable. In grignard reagent, there is a Carbon-Magnesium bond which is highly polar.
Carbon cannot make 5 2e-2C bonds, therefore we will have to break a bond if grignard attacks. Therefore grignard attacks ketone carbon because is has partial positive charge and also breaking C=O $\pi$ bond is easier. Simultaneously, the [MgBr]+ shifts to oxygen and stabilizes it. So, indeed MgBr does form a bond with O-. Now, when we put water in 2nd step, the O-Mg bond, will break and the bond electrons attack H of water, forming alcohol. MgBr goes to the OH- of the water.
Extra tip: Might be helpful, grignard attacks aldehyde ketones first, then attacks acid chloride. Other nucleophilic addition reagents attack acid chloride first. So if 1eq of grignard was given, we will attack ketone.
